# Quorum Data Migration

Tags: quorum

In the forseeable future, there will be a need to migrate data on the Quorum blockchain to another system.

Are there migration tools/ETL tools that can take data on blockchain nodes and process it in a datawarehouse for data analytics/backup and/or archive it in a format that can retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific tools that I am aware of at the moment.